# Would like to create access task list with checkboxes, but unsure how to set up the tables

Tags: database, ms-access

[Potential Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZeYk.jpg)

[Final form look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM3my.jpg)

I'm uncertain if this table structure is correct for what I want.  For one thing, I don't really want a date next to each task, because all of the tasks should reflect one date -- this is a form for the day, where all the tasks completed go with the same day: the form is for that day, so if 7 are checked, that's one day.  12 may be checked the next.

I was also thinking about laying out every task as its own field, with one date field of course, solving the date issue, but that feels wrong.

Should I consider making a second table that links to the tasks with the fields done, date, taskID(FK).

Looking for suggestions on table structure, thanks!

Comment: You should have Task1 and task2 in the same row. Doing that is going to make your table flat and is going to cause a headache later.

Comment: I also dont see why there cant be a date in each row - its pretty standard.

Comment: @DougCoats Because I don't want to have to enter a completion date many times, they all fall under the same day, so I only need one date per all the tasks.  If I complete 15 of them, I don't want to have to enter 15 dates.

Comment: You knw youre using a sql engine, right? That shouldnt be a concern (not even in the slightest)

Comment: @DougCoats Ugh, I made an error in the naming of field "Task2."  That's not a separate task, it's a subcategory of HabitArea, it's a more specific detailing of the Habit area: Habit area is just Art, but art has 3 subtasks, art practice, art creation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you'd be better off with soemthing like this:

[image]

Yes, it will make inserts a bit more annoying, but however, the table structure you outlined, is clearly a one-to-many relaitonship. It woul dbe more correct to design your tables in a more relational way, and then account for it by the way you wrote code. This will also allow you to insert rows for each level of difficulty as well (assuming youre allowing end users to multi select).

You could even stretch this out a bit further and make another look up table for your notes, since they seem to be pretty standardized and then have the noteID in your tblActivity. This would essentially make tblActivity your main table, with all the nonsense you dont necessarily need in look up tables.

Comment: @dDougCoats Thanks for taking the time to help.  I appreciate it. I'm not looking to make each task its own entry/row.  For any given day, many tasks can be completed, so there's one date for all of them.  Also you say the relationship is one to many, which is the one and which is the many?

Comment: Well in your example you have tadsk1 and task2 in one row, it shoul dbe obvious that the task itself has to things, or activities, related to it. Thats the basic definition of a one to many.

Comment: Should each checkbox on the form have its own field in the table, so that for each thing checked, it counts as one record and has one date?

Comment: @picayuni The more I think about it, you could actually just do without the done file din the table and only log records where they checked done.

Comment: And I wouldnt log all levels either - it should be implied that if they reached elite that had to have done the previous levels.